# Checking android heap size

Tags: java, android, air-native-extension

Is there a good way to check how much memory out of overall heap size has the device in Java?
My app, which is written in adobe air, uses native Java extension to load multiple images from SD Card. I found this piece of code to check if bitmap could be loaded into memory:

```
public boolean checkBitmapFitsInMemory(long bmpwidth,long bmpheight, int bmpdensity ){

        long reqsize=bmpwidth*bmpheight*bmpdensity;
        long allocNativeHeap = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
        final long heapPad=(long)Math.max(4*1024*1024,Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()*0.1);
        if ((reqsize + allocNativeHeap + heapPad) >= Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

However, it seems that on my Galaxy S2 it is completely ignored. Maybe because the app consists of two parts - one is Java second is adobe air. Is there another memory values i should check before loading image into applications memory? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Android Runtime](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html)

Calling `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` returns memory resources available to the running application.

Also, [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked freeMemory() from the Log and it does not make sense. It is changing with each loaded image, but sometimes it is growing! before loading first image it was 1070032, after loading 20 images it is 1698688. Kinda frustrating.

Comment: But this could be true. Your application is not the only one using memory, is it?

Comment: So it is not practical in my case. I need to know will the OS shut down my app with a next image loaded to memory

Comment: Did you check the other link I posted in the last line?

Comment: I checked the first one again, this seems to be ok: Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()